# Set Meeting Conversation audio programmatically using lync 2013 sdk

Tags: lync-2013

I am using Lync SDK 2013 to automate lync  [skype for business] actions. Eg. When user says Join first meeting, lync.exe is launched and first meeting from pre-displayed list is joined in lync client on the machine. This automates clicking on "Join Skype Meeting" in meeting invite from Microsoft Outlook Calender.

I am using "lyncClient.ConversationManager.JoinConference(meetinguri)" to start meeting.

After meeting is started, I get standard "Join Meeting Audio" dialog which has three options to choose audio like dont join, call me at and join skype for business (full audio and video)

I want to suppress this dialog and somehow send audio setting for this meeting conversation through SIP url or API.

How to achieve this?

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

AJ

Answer (score 0):

The Lync Client SDK does not give you this level of control.

If you wish to control these settings, you can control them with the registry.  See this [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dodeitte/2011/11/10/how-to-automate-the-join-meeting-audio-dialog-box/).  Even though the article is for an older version of Lync client it's still valid, you just need to translate the registry key to the new location:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office[version]\Lync

where version is the office version installed. e.g. "16.0", "15.0", etc.

You may need to restart the Lync client before the registry settings become active though. You will have to test this.

If you wish to actually automate the UI, then your options are then reduced to using something like the [Windows Automation API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/windows-automation-api-portal).  These work fine with the Lync Client but they are a pain to figure out the required steps to automate anything.